# ddrescue only recovers subset of DVD

Tags: iso, dvd, ddrescue

If I use the following command, I get a well-formed ISO which is 4.3 GB in size.

```
readom dev=/dev/sr0 f=img1.iso
```

If I use ddrescue however, it produces a 1 GB ISO, even though ddrescue does not encounter any errors.

```
ddrescue -n -b2048 /dev/sr0 img2.iso
```

The file is only the first 1,073,741,312 bytes of the DVD.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Operating system: Debian

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded to the latest version of Clonezilla and ddrescue now produces the correct sized ISO.